# List<String> to Json String

Tags: java, json

How can I convert a List to a Json String?

I have managed to do it the other way round, but not this way.

I also don't know how I can specify the names of the keys then..

Comment: How did you do it "other way round"? Did you use some library?

Comment: What utility do you use ? gson ? None ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Gson Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
List<String> list;
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

**Edited**:

Just to have the complete answer here: The problem is that you are converting the json String into a `List<String>`. This way you are losing the relation key-value. The correct should be convert the json string into a `HashMap<>`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have done this now, but it seems that only the values are in this json String, but not the keys. How can I put them to this json String?

Comment: @Jane A `List<String>` does not contain key/value pairs.

Comment: What would be the keys in a `List<String>` ?

Comment: Yes this is the problem. But I need Keys again in my Json String! How can I put them? 
It is like this: At the beginning I have a well-structured Json String. I put this into a List, remove some elements, and want to but this back to Json with new names for the keys. How can I do this?

Comment: Dont put it in a `List`. Use `HashMap` to conserve the keys.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your real problem is that when you originally turned the JSON string into a `List`, you threw away the keys.  And that is not surprising, a List is not a natural representation of a JSON object (i.e. a thing with key - value pairs).  You probably should have represented it as a `Map`.

But anyway, if you threw away the keys you've go a problem.  You need to either you change your data structure to not throw the keys away, or reconstruct the JSON by inferring what the keys *should* be based on (for instance) their position in the list.  (The latter could be a bit dodgy because the order of the name/value pairs in the original JSON should not signify anything ... and could be "random" or "implementation dependent".

Comment: I have already solved it. Instead of turning it to a List I will turn it to a Hash Map!